# Долго преобразует большой xml через xslt в html что делать?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Вобщем есть документы xml большие, по 9мб. Специфичные данные.
Для них есть шаблоны xslt. Если я обрезаю документ, укорачиваю его до 500кб. все срабатывает быстро, пробовал через браузер, php и xsltproc (на ubuntu сервер) все работает. Но вот оригинальный документ, все зависает, браузер виснет, а утилита xsltproc долго долго работает, но я так и не дождался конца.

Есть способы как то ускорить процесс?

Вобще мне надо чтобы все работало на php

Comment: На такие обьемы лучше делать преобразования внешним модулем, написаном, допустим на с++. И... возможно процессинг делать не через библиотеку xml, сама серия библиотек msxml_xx.dll работает довольно медленно с такими обьемами.

Comment: Можно попробовать запустить процесс преобразования в отдельном потоке, и каждую минуту отдавать, например пробел и делать `flush()` плюс показать какую-нибудь анимацию вроде "ожидайте". По готовности - отдать страницу и скрипт js который потушит анимацию.

Comment: это все понятно с анимациями и ожиданиями. а вот специализированная утилита xsltproc она разве не на С написана? может есть еще какая то утилита. я у меньшил файл до 3.5 мб на нем тоже зависает все напроч и не могу я дождаться конца... неприемлимо. понимаю если ждать ну минуту максимум, но я ждал минут 30 и выключил...

Comment: Может быть и на си, но видимо она не рассчитана на большие обьемы. Мне кажется что сама спецификация настолько сложная... что сложно (или невозможно) это сделать. Если там GC+вариантные типы - то она точно на небольшие обьемы. Для часного случая можно. Мой опыт xslt преобразований показал что с большими обьемами преобразователи плохо справляются.

Comment: ну я где то на форумах читал, там файлы под 100-500 мб суют этой утилите xsltproc  она норм их перерабатывает. тут видимо может сама структура сложная очень...